# Attempting to sort a linked list

Tags: java, debugging, linked-list

I am already aware of various answers to this question. But I have a very confusing bug in my code. The following is a series of println() calls to see if the list I created is correctly sorted.

```
ListNode list_b = new ListNode(3, new ListNode(-2));
System.out.println("Checking the string conversion: " +
sut.convertToString(list_b));    //output is 3,-2, as expected. Expected result of sorting is -2,3.

System.out.println("Now checking the 
string conversion of the sorted list: " +
sut.convertToString(sut.sort(list_b, int_comparator))); //output is -2,3 as expected.

System.out.println("Now this is list_b following the sorting,
by calling the element and next directly: " 
+ list_b.element + "," + list_b.next);      //3,null. How the hell did that happen!?!??!!?
```

The convertToString method is as follows:

```
public String convertToString(ListNode head) {
    if (head != null) {
        String representation = "";
        if (!head.element.equals(null))
            representation += head.element.toString();
        ListNode next = null;
        if (head.next != null)
            next = head.next;
        if (next != null && !next.element.equals(null))
            representation += "," + next.element.toString();
        while (next != null) {
            if (next.next != null) {
                next = next.next;
                if (!next.element.equals(null))
                    representation += "," + next.element.toString();
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        return representation;
    }
    else
        return "";
}
```

And the actual sort method is still a work in progress, albeit fairly simple:

```
public ListNode sort(ListNode head, Comparator comparator) {
    if (head != null) {
        ListNode next = null;
        if (head.next != null)
            next = head.next;
        else
            return head;
        if (comparator.compare(head.element, next.element) > 0) {
            head.next = next.next;
            next.next = head;
            head = next;
        }
        return head;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Would anyone care to explain how I've managed to do the seemingly impossible? I'm speechless at how this could happen! Many thanks to anyone who can explain!

EDIT: thank you to those for your answers and suggestions. I should clarify that the following tests are then performed on the list:

```
assertTrue(sut.deepEquals(list_a, sut.sort(list_a, int_comparator)));
assertFalse(sut.deepEquals(list_b, sut.sort(list_b, int_comparator)));

assertTrue(sut.deepEquals(new ListNode(-2, new ListNode(3)), sut.sort(list_b, int_comparator)));
assertTrue(sut.deepEquals(new ListNode(-14, new ListNode(-2, new ListNode(3))), sut.sort(list_c, int_comparator)));
```

Clearly, this implies that any updating of list_b (i.e. list_b = sut.sort(list_b)) is unnecessary. What I'm asking is how you would change the sort method itself so that updating is unnecessary.

Comment: See the addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple: you sort the list in this piece of code:

```
sut.convertToString(sut.sort(list_b, int_comparator)))
```

The list is transformed this way:

```
3 -> -2 -> null  ====> -2 -> 3 -> null
^                            ^
|                            |
list_b                       list_b
```

`sut.sort` returns the new front (head) of the list, which should be the new `list_b`, but since you don't update the value, it points to the second node in the list, thus producing `"3 , null"`

Comment: But in the sort method, don't I return head, which has been supposedly set to the node containing -2? More importantly, how do I 'undo' this sorting if what you say is true?

Comment: the method returns the new head of the list, but you'll have to do something like `list_b = sut.sort(...);` in order to update the value of `list_b`. as for undoing the sorting: in this case it's pretty simple, since all you need to do is swap the two nodes back. But in general it's impossible to restore the state before sorting, unless the previous state was sorted by some property aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Well ... you are changing the internals of the passed node inside your `sort` method. The variable `list_b` is still referring to the node "3" that after sorting does not have a successor anymore.

Your sort method is returning the new head of the sorted list. But you do not use that afterwards!

Change your code snippet to:

```
list_b = sut.sort(list_b, int_comparator);
System.out.println(sut.convertToString(list_b));
```

Comment: That does work - but how would you suggest I then write the sort method to return the correct 'head' of the list?

Comment: I do not understand your question. You already return the correct head of the list. So what are you actually asking here?

Comment: I'm trying to do JUnit tests on the sort and convertToString operations. They don't update the value of list_b, which implies that I shouldn't need to write list_b = etc. What I'm asking is how I should change the sort method so that I don't need to write list_b = etc in the first place. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your sort method returns the new head. You have to use that reutrn value which simply means to assign it to a variable. If you don't want to have it that way, you must design your list class in another way.

Answer (score 0):

`list_b` references the node containing 3, and having the node 2 as next element.

Then you sort the list. That changes the node containing 3: its next node is now null, since it becomes the last element of the list. It also changes the node 2, which now has the node 3 as next element. But list_b continues to be a reference to the node containing 3.

When you print the node list_b, you thus get `3, null` as a result.

EDIT:

to answer your last question:

> how you would change the sort method itself so that updating is unnecessary

You should have an actual LinkedList class (exactly as the standard java.util.LinkedList class). The class you have doesn't represent a list. It represents a node inside a chain of nodes.

The LinkedList class  would have a reference to the head node, and would contain all the methods needed to iterate through the values stored in the list, transform it to a String, sort it, etc. Of course, sorting the list would imply changing the reference to the head node inside the LinkedList object. But that would be transparent to the user of the LinkedList class, which would never manipulated nodes directly.

Of course, if you start caring so much about having a proper LinkedList class, you should simply use the standard one, which is standard, documented, and tested.